# mysql order by group with with alphabetical order

Tags: mysql

example in database:

```
felhasznalonev tipus
TOM            1
DICK           2
HARRY          1
```

I have asking

```
SELECT elsotabla.felhasznalonev, elsotabla.tipus
GROUP BY elsotabla.tipus
```

but this query return me tom 1 as first and I will hawing it in ordered by group and in group type the names in alphabetical order. Can somebody me help?

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT elsotabla.felhasznalonev, elsotabla.tipus
ORDER BY elsotabla.felhasznalonev ASC;
```

That would order the query by some field in ascending order.